# Is there any way to write UI tests for force touch actions on a iOS app?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, xcode-ui-testing, 3dtouch, quickaction

I was trying to write UI tests for home screen quick actions that I implemented for my iOS app. So when I start recording UI workflows, it doesn't let me capture the force touch events on the app. Instead it ignores the force touch and immediately opens the app (making it a tap event).

Is there any possible way with the latest Xcode8 that I can UI test home page quick actions? I have tried recording both the simulator and the actual device, nothing works. FYI the force touch actions work fine when I am normally open the app and trigger them.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39284082/make-xcuielement-perform-3d-touch-for-automate-uitest

Comment: I don't think you can set `launchOptions` which is pretty unfortunate. Hopefully something changes in the future.